# Remove HTML Textarea resize icon

Tags: html, css, text

So in my project, I am using a `<textarea>` element to type, but I was wondering, is there any way to remove THIS icon that is in default when inserting the textarea to the page:

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Yes, those 2 lines that appear at the right bottom of the text box. Is there any way with CSS or something to remove that small icon?

Comment: Yes, many people say that with resize none, but I want it to be resizable, what I don't want is to show the small icon at the bottom :(

Answer (score -1):

```
    <textarea style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

The icon you are refering to is used to resize the textarea which is resizable by default. we can use the resize property to disable the resizability:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: can you add an explanation why that answer works?

Comment: The answer was pretty expliciitly asking to remove the icon itsself, not disable resizing.